# OCUnit test for protocols/callbacks/delegate in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, delegates, ocunit

Using OCUnit, is there a way to test delegate protocols?

I'm trying this, which doesn't work.

```
-(void) testSomeObjDelegate {
  SomeObj obj = [[SomeObj alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
  [obj executeMethod];
}
-(void) someObjDelegateMethod {
  //test something here
}
```

I'm going to try calling the `obj` method on a different thread and have the test sleep until the delegate is called.  It just seems like there should be an easier way to test this.

Comment: Mike Ash has a wonderful article on the topic: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-07-22-writing-unit-tests.html

Answer (score 53):

Testing a delegate is trivial.  Just set an ivar in the test in your callback method, and check it after what should be triggering the delegate callback.

For example, if I have a class `Something` that uses a delegate of protocol `SomethingDelegate` and sends that delegate `-something:delegateInvoked:` in response to some message, I can test it lik ethis:

```
@interface TestSomeBehavior : SenTestCase <SomethingDelegate>
{
    Something *_object;
    BOOL _callbackInvoked;
}
@end

@implementation TestSomeBehavior

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    _object = [[Something alloc] init];
    _object.delegate = self;
}

- (void)tearDown {
    _object.delegate = nil;
    [_object release];
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testSomeBehaviorCallingBack {
    [_object doSomethingThatShouldCallBack];

    STAssertTrue(_callbackInvoked,
                 @"Delegate should send -something:delegateInvoked:");
}

- (void)something:(Something *)something delegateInvoked:(BOOL)invoked {
    _callbackInvoked = YES;
}

@end
```

I think you already understand this, however, from the way you've phrased your question.  (I'm mostly posting this for other readers.)  I think you're actually asking a more subtle question:  How do I test something that **may occur later** such as something that spins the runloop.  My cue is your mention of sleeping and threading.

First off, you **should not** just arbitrarily invoke a method on another thread.  You should only do so if it's documented to be safe to use in that way.  The reason is that you don't know what the internals of the class do.  For example, it might schedule events on the run loop, in which case running the method on a different thread will make them happen on a different run loop. This would then screw up the class's internal state.

If you **do** need to test something that may take a little time to happen, you can do this just by running the current run loop.  Here's how I might rewrite the individual test method above to do that:

```
- (void)testSomeBehaviorCallingBack {
    NSDate *fiveSecondsFromNow = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.0];

    [_object doSomethingThatShouldCallBack];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:fiveSecondsFromNow];

    STAssertTrue(_callbackInvoked,
                 @"Delegate should send -something:delegateInvoked:");
}
```

This will spin the current run loop in the default mode for 5 seconds, under the assumption that `-doSomethingThatShouldCallBack` will schedule its work on the main run loop in the default mode.  This is usually OK because APIs that work this way often let you specify a run loop to use as well as a mode to run in.  If you can do that, then you can use `-[NSRunLoop runMode:beforeDate:]` to run the run loop in just that mode instead, making it more likely that the work you're expecting to be done will be.

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was having. Thanks for the succinct answer. This solved it for me.

Comment: Maybe capsulating the delegate functionality in a (mock) object would make this method nicer. I'm still searching for a more natural unit test method for asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: Best answer! Helped me with my problem

Answer (score 12):

Please, review [Unit Testing Asynchronous Network Access](http://www.infinite-loop.dk/blog/2011/04/unittesting-asynchronous-network-access/). I think can help you.
In short what it does is:

> Add the following method which will take care of the synchronization
>   between the unit test code and the asynchronous code under test:

```
- (BOOL)waitForCompletion:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutSecs {
    NSDate *timeoutDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeoutSecs];

    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:timeoutDate];
        if([timeoutDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0)
            break;
    } while (!done);

    return done;
}
```