# iOS unit test: How to unit test firstResponderStatus

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest, first-responder

I am writing a test to confirm the if a method shifts the focus to next textField. I tried the code from [iOS unit test: How to set/update/examine firstResponder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079073/ios-unit-test-how-to-set-update-examine-firstresponder). But it fails.

```
- (void)testFocusMovedToYearField {
  UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
  [window addSubview:self.dateCell.txtDay];
  [window addSubview:self.dateCell.txtYear];   
  [self.dateCell completionBlockHelper];
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.0]]; 
  XCTAssertTrue([self.kioskDateCell.txtYear isFirstResponder]);
}
```

The function `completionBlockHelper` contains the code to make the `txtYear` become first responder.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: This works for me. Are you sure that `self.dateCell.txtYear` is not `nil`? Are you sure `completionBlockHelper` is getting invoked? Try stepping through the test to try and figure out what's going on.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure `self.dateCell.txtYear`  is not nil and  `completionBlockHelper` is invoked as well.  I also tried replacing `[self.dateCell completionBlockHelper]` with `[self.dateCell.txtYear becomeFirstResponder]` just to check if that works but no luck.

Comment: any update? I am experiencing the same issue. Tried putting in a fake dummy view to no avail

Answer (score 1):

The window needs to become the key window. In Swift: `window.makeKeyAndVisible()`