# How to test delegate call back using GHUnit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, unit-testing

I'm trying to write testcase for test my delegates. For example,

```
-(void)testUserLogin{
    loginRequest=[[RTUserLoginRequest alloc]initWithUserNmae:@"1235" password:@"1235"];
    [loginRequest setDelegate:self];
    [loginRequest invoke];


}

-(void)userLoginRequest:(RTUserLoginRequest *)request didSucceed:(BOOL)succeed{

    GHTestLog(@"user login succeed");
}
```

This code run perfectly but problem is when this callback fired it not display in simulator like testUserLogin. What is the standard method to test this kind of situation

Comment: See this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077737/ocunit-test-for-protocols-callbacks-delegate-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)testUserPendingRequest{
    userPendingRequest =[[RTCheckUserPendingRequest alloc]initWithUserNmae:@"123"];
    [userPendingRequest setDelegate:self];
    [userPendingRequest invoke];
    [self waitForCompletion:2];
    GHAssertTrue(_isDelegateInvoked, @"check user available invoked");

}

-(void)checkUserPendingRequest:(RTCheckUserPendingRequest *)request isUserPending:(BOOL)pending{
    _isDelegateInvoked=YES;
    if(pending)
        GHTestLog(@"user Pending ");
    else
        GHTestLog(@"User Active");
}

- (BOOL)waitForCompletion:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutSecs {
    NSDate *timeoutDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeoutSecs];

    do {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:timeoutDate];
        if([timeoutDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0)
            break;
    } while (!_isDelegateInvoked);

    return _isDelegateInvoked;
}
```